# Не работает шейдер! OpenGL, Qt, C++

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Шейдеры компилируются, линкуются.

Ожидается увидеть цветной куб на фиолетовом фоне. Получается куб чёрный.

Заголовочный файл:

```
struct VertexData {

    VertexData() {}

    VertexData(QVector3D p, QVector2D t, QVector3D n) : position (p),
        texCoord(t), normal(n) {}

    QVector3D position;
    QVector2D texCoord;
    QVector3D normal;
};

class Widget : public QOpenGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

protected:

    void initializeGL(); 
    void resizeGL(int w, int h); 
    void paintGL();

    void initShaders();

    void initCube(float width);

private:

    QMatrix4x4 ProjectionMatrix;

    QOpenGLShaderProgram ShaderProgram;

    QOpenGLTexture *m_texture;

    QOpenGLBuffer ArrayBuffer;

    QOpenGLBuffer IndexBuffer;
};
```

cpp:

```
    Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
        : QOpenGLWidget(parent), m_texture(0), IndexBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer::IndexBuffer)
    {
    }

    Widget::~Widget()
    {
    }
    
    void Widget::initializeGL()
    {
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST | GL_CULL_FACE);
    
        initShaders();
    
        initCube(1.0f);
    
        m_texture->bind(0);
    }
    
    void Widget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
    {
        float aspect = w / (float)h;
    
        ProjectionMatrix.setToIdentity();
        ProjectionMatrix.perspective(45, aspect, 0.1f, 10.0f);
    }
    
    void Widget::paintGL()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    
        QMatrix4x4 ModelViewMatrix;
        ModelViewMatrix.setToIdentity();
        ModelViewMatrix.translate(0.0, 0.0, -5.0);
        ModelViewMatrix.rotate(30, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        ModelViewMatrix.rotate(30, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    
        ShaderProgram.bind();
        ShaderProgram.setUniformValue("qt_ModelViewProjectionMatrix", ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix);
        ShaderProgram.setUniformValue("qt_Texture0", 0); 
    
    
        int VertLoc = ShaderProgram.attributeLocation("qt_Vertex");
        ShaderProgram.enableAttributeArray(VertLoc);
        ShaderProgram.setAttributeBuffer(VertLoc, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3, sizeof(VertexData));
    
        int texLoc = ShaderProgram.attributeLocation("qt_MultiTexCoord0");
        ShaderProgram.enableAttributeArray(texLoc);
        ShaderProgram.setAttributeBuffer(texLoc, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(QVector3D), 2, sizeof(VertexData));
    
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, IndexBuffer.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
    
    void Widget::initShaders()
    {
       if (!ShaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, ":/vshader.vsh"))
           exit(-230);
    
       if (!ShaderProgram.addCacheableShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, ":/fshader.fsh"))
           exit(-229);
    
       if (!ShaderProgram.link())
           exit(-228);
    }
    
    void Widget::initCube(float width)
    {
        float w_by2 = width / 2.0f;
    
        QVector<VertexData> vertexes;
    
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(-w_by2, w_by2, w_by2), QVector2D(0.0, 1.0), QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(-w_by2, -w_by2, w_by2), QVector2D(0.0, 0.0), QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(w_by2, w_by2, w_by2), QVector2D(1.0, 1.0), QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(w_by2, -w_by2, w_by2), QVector2D(1.0, 0.0), QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)));
    
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(w_by2, w_by2, w_by2), QVector2D(0.0, 1.0), QVector3D(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(w_by2, -w_by2, w_by2), QVector2D(0.0, 0.0), QVector3D(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(w_by2, w_by2, -w_by2), QVector2D(1.0, 1.0), QVector3D(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(w_by2, -w_by2, -w_by2), QVector2D(1.0, 0.0), QVector3D(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)));
    
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(w_by2, w_by2, w_by2), QVector2D(0.0, 1.0), QVector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(w_by2, w_by2, -w_by2), QVector2D(0.0, 0.0), QVector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(-w_by2, w_by2, w_by2), QVector2D(1.0, 1.0), QVector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(-w_by2, w_by2, -w_by2), QVector2D(1.0, 0.0), QVector3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)));
    
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(w_by2, w_by2, -w_by2), QVector2D(0.0, 1.0), QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(w_by2, -w_by2, -w_by2), QVector2D(0.0, 0.0), QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(-w_by2, w_by2, -w_by2), QVector2D(1.0, 1.0), QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(-w_by2, -w_by2, -w_by2), QVector2D(1.0, 0.0), QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)));
    
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(-w_by2, w_by2, w_by2), QVector2D(0.0, 1.0), QVector3D(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(-w_by2, w_by2, -w_by2), QVector2D(0.0, 0.0), QVector3D(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(-w_by2, -w_by2, w_by2), QVector2D(1.0, 1.0), QVector3D(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(-w_by2, -w_by2, -w_by2), QVector2D(1.0, 0.0), QVector3D(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)));
    
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(-w_by2, -w_by2, w_by2), QVector2D(0.0, 1.0), QVector3D(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(-w_by2, -w_by2, -w_by2), QVector2D(0.0, 0.0), QVector3D(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(w_by2, -w_by2, w_by2), QVector2D(1.0, 1.0), QVector3D(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)));
        vertexes.append(VertexData(QVector3D(w_by2, -w_by2, -w_by2), QVector2D(1.0, 0.0), QVector3D(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)));
    
        QVector<GLuint> indexes;
    
        for (short i = 0; i < 24; i += 4) {
    
            indexes.append(i + 0);
            indexes.append(i + 1);
            indexes.append(i + 2);
            indexes.append(i + 2);
            indexes.append(i + 1);
            indexes.append(i + 3);
        }
    
        ArrayBuffer.create();
    
        ArrayBuffer.bind();
    
        ArrayBuffer.allocate(vertexes.constData(), vertexes.size() * sizeof(VertexData));
    
        IndexBuffer.create();
    
        IndexBuffer.bind();
    
        IndexBuffer.allocate(indexes.constData(), indexes.size() * sizeof(GLuint));
    
        m_texture = new QOpenGLTexture(QImage(":/large.png").mirrored());
    
        m_texture->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Nearest);
    
        m_texture->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Linear);
    
        m_texture->setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::Repeat);
    }
```

вершинный шейдер:

```
attribute highp vec4 qt_Vertex;
attribute highp vec2 qt_MultiTexCoord0;
uniform highp mat4 qt_ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = qt_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * qt_Vertex;
    qt_TexCoord0 = qt_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

фрагментный:

```
uniform sampler2D qt_Texture0;
varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Код был написан и запущен на версии Qt 5.9.9.
Если запустить на версии Qt 6.0+, то всё заработает.